# Why did the Camarilla accept the Banu Haqim (Assamites) but refuse the Ministry (Followers of Set)?

Tags: world-of-darkness, lore, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

I have read from the web and the Camarilla book that Banu Haqim are part of the sect. I also read that they refuse the Ministry (and betray them).

But I don't understand why. Banu Haqim are known diablerist, which the Ministry isn't. Plus the Banu Haqim are just assassins and sorcerers (which the Camarilla has already).

Can you help me to understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: **politics.**

More detailed answer:

1. It's not all the Banu Haqim, it's just one **faction** within them which has joined the Camarilla. There's another lot who have stuck with the Ashirra, and a third lot who follow the newly awoken methuselah Ur-Shulgi. The latter live up to every stereotype of mad diablerists who want to kill all other Kindred. The faction who have joined the Camarilla are more 'user friendly' than the Ur-Shulgi lot, and will defend the Camarilla from them. (The Camarilla are also making an alliance with the Ashirra). [Source: the *Camarilla* sourcebook, p157-162, plus comments in various letters by Victoria Ash throughout that book]
2. Traditionally the **Tremere** hated the Banu Haqim (and vice versa) and would have been using their influence to keep them out of the Camarilla. However, the power of the Tremere is broken. The Vienna Chantry is gone, destroyed by humans. Clan Tremere has splintered into 4 factions, at least one of which has thrown its lot in with the Anarchs. So that means a major source of objection to Banu Haqim joining has gone. [Source: *VTM5e Core Rules* on the fall of the Tremere, plus the 4th faction of the Tremere, House Ipsissimus, is in the *Anarch* source book p170-2. Page 158 of the  *Camarilla* sourcebook states the Banu Haqim told the humans the location of the Tremere Chantry].
3. In game mechanic terms, both Tremere and Banu Haqim get the **Blood Sorcery** discipline (replaces Thaumaturgy from earlier editions). If the Camarilla leadership are short of wizards because the usual Tremere are dead or disorganised, then some Banu Haqim can fulfill exactly the same role. [Source: Banu Haqim chapter of the *Camarilla* sourcebook]
4. The **Brujah and Gangrel** have left the Camarilla and joined the Anarchs. Oh dear, that means there is no longer a handy source of thugs and enforcers, red shirts and ablative armour for the great and the good of the Camarilla to throw at problems. But you can use Banu Haqim assassins to fulfill the same role. [Source: *VTM5e Core Rules* and *Anarch* on the Gangrel & Brujah leaving the Camarilla].

And a quote from the *Camarilla* sourcebook, p158 on the Banu Haqim joining the Camarilla:

> Three things happened to make their admission a possibility: the first was the Brujah departure; the second was the Tremere loss in Vienna; the third was the Sabbat's Gehenna Crusade, that gave us a common enemy on the battlefields of our homelands.

5. The Anarch sourcebook says the Ministry (Setites) petitioned to join the Camarilla but were turned down. The reason being that Ministry bigwigs met with Camarilla bigwigs in Paris to discuss the matter, when the hotel and all the buildings around it **blew up**. No-one knows for sure who did it. Rumours say it was the Banu Haqim, seeing a great opportunity to get rid of hated rivals. When the surviving Ministry later contacted the Camarilla about the proposed alliance, they were told to get lost. [Source: *Camarilla* p158, *Anarch* p182-3] I guess you could read into that that all the powerful Camarilla folks who were pro-Ministry died in the explosion, and their deaths means the anti-Ministry folks are now in charge.